# Trying to extend getName in my Magento Custom Extension?

Tags: magento, block, extend, adminhtml

Quick overview even though I think the below code will explain itself. I am wanting to extend the getName() public function and truncate it. However my code does nothing and does not even throw an error. Here is are my files.

Beckin/TextShortner/etc/config.xml

```
<config>    
<modules>
<Beckin_TextShortner><version>1.0.0</version></Beckin_TextShortner>
    </modules>

<global>           
            <models>
               <textshortner>
                     <class>Beckin_TextShortner_Model</class>
               </textshortner>
            </models>
    <helpers>
         <textshortner>
          <class>Beckin_TextShortner_Helper</class>
         </textshortner>
    </helpers>      
</global>


<textshortner>
  <settings>
    <enable>1</enable>
  </settings>
</textshortner>


 <frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <beckin>
                <file>beckin_textshortner.xml</file>
            </beckin>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <routers>
        <textshortner>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Beckin_TextShortner</module>
                <frontName>textshortner</frontName>
            </args>
        </textshortner>
    </routers>  
</frontend>

</config>
```

Beckin/TextShortner/Model/Catalog/Product.php

```
class Beckin_TextShortner_Model_Catalog_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Catalog_Product
{   

public function getName()
{
$getmyName = $this->_getData('name');
return  $this->helper('core/string')->truncate($getmyName,10); 
}

}
```

Beckin/TextShortner/etc/system.xml

```
<config>
<tabs>
    <beckin translate="label">
        <label>Beckin Extensions</label>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    </beckin>
</tabs>

<sections>  
            <textshortner translate="label">
        <label>Text Shortner</label>
        <tab>beckin</tab>
        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
        <sort_order>1010</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>


            <groups>            

                <settings translate="label">
                <label>Settings</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

                    <fields>
                        <enable translate="label">
                        <label>Enable</label>
                        <comment>
                        <![CDATA[Enable or Disable this extension.]]>
                        </comment>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
                        </enable>           
                    </fields>

                </settings>
            </groups>
        </textshortner>
</sections>     
</config>
```

Beckin/TextShortner/etc/adminhtml.xml

```
<config>  

    <acl>
        <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <textshortner>
                                        <title>Beckin Text Shortner Extension</title>
                                    </textshortner>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>

</config>
```

and of-course I got my modules xml file set as well.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here, but if you're simply trying to make sure `getName()` returns a defined length of characters, why not just do that in your template file using the truncate helper method?

Comment: Hello, I am aware that I can do that. However, I am wanting to build an extension that does this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things the model you extend Mage_Catalog_Model_Catalog_Product
I think this is not the right name for the model ??

did you mean ?   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product

Second with your code you extended the model but you didn't rewrite the model.
So you have to change the model the in block files in the core pool which is not good.

So what u need to do here is to specify rewrite for the model in your  config.xml

```
<models>
....
<catalog>
      <rewrite>
            <product>Beckin_TextShortner_Model_Catalog_Product</product>
      </rewrite>
</catalog>
....
</models>
```

Then you will be able to use the method without issues

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't see the double Catalog. Thanks!